# converting for loop to foreach

Tags: c#, for-loop, foreach

So I have this piece of code that works fine, how ever for my assignment the professor wants the code to work with a foreach statment.  The only way I could get it to work was with a for loop.  Anyone know how to convert the for loop into a foreach statment?

here's the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CheckZips.cs
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] zips = new int[10] { 07950, 07840, 07828, 07836, 07928, 07869, 07849, 07852, 07960, 07876 };

        int correctZipCode;
        int input;

        Console.WriteLine("Enter a zip code.");
        input = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        correctZipCode = Convert.ToInt32(input);

        bool found = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < zips.Length; ++i)
        {
            if(correctZipCode == zips[i])
            {
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (found)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("We deliver to that zip code.");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("We do not deliver to that zip code.");
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: `foreach(var item in zips) { if(correctZipCode == item) ...}`? By the way, integers _can't_ have leading zeros. So they are actually will be `7950, 7840` etc.

Comment: Or just one line in Linq `bool found = zips.Any(zip => zip == correctZipCode)`

Comment: Take a look at [foreach](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/ttw7t8t6.aspx).

Comment: Zip codes are strings, not integers, and can have significant leading zeros and alphabetic characters.

Answer (score 2):

A `foreach` can be implemented like this:

```
foreach (int zip in zips)
{
    if (zip == correctZipCode)
    {
      found = true;
      break;
    }
}
```